# Extract first word

Tags: r, regex

I have the following data frame dat :

```
brand (column name)
Channel clothes
Gucci perfume
Channel shoes
LV purses
LV scarves
```

And I want to create a new column with just the brand name so the first word of column brand regardless of what follows. I want output as below:

```
brand (column name)
Channel
Gucci
Channel
LV
LV
```

I have tried to use sub with below codes but it doesn't work. Could you please help out what is wrong with my code?

```
brand <- sub("(\\w+).*", "\\1", dat$brand)
```

Comment: Use `sub(" .*$", "", dat$brand)` to delete everything following the first space.

Comment: `?stringi::stri_extract_first_words`

Answer (score 14):

We can use the `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(df$brand, 1)
#[1] "Channel" "Gucci"   "Channel" "LV"      "LV"
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
dat <- data.frame(Brand = c('Channel clothes',
                           'Gucci perfume',
                           'Channel shoes',
                           'LV purses',
                           'LV scarves'))
brand <- sub('(^\\w+)\\s.+','\\1',dat$Brand)
#[1] "Channel" "Gucci"   "Channel" "LV"      "LV"
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the `tidyverse` approach.

With this dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~brand,
  "Channel clothes",
  "Gucci perfume",
  "Channel shoes",
  "LV purses",
  "LV scarves"
)
```

We can separate the column with the following:

```
df %>% 
  separate(brand, into = c("brand", "item"), sep = " ")
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
    brand    item
*   <chr>   <chr>
1 Channel clothes
2   Gucci perfume
3 Channel   shoes
4      LV  purses
5      LV scarves
```